# Map over a multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, nested

I am requiring a simple way to apply a function across a multidimensional nested list.
I see many answers recommending list comprehension or nested list comprehension, but given the **precondition** that my list can have 'n' number of nestings, the equation indeed becomes complicated.

input

```
x = ['apple', ['banana','blossom'], ['cherry', ['jackfruit' , 'guava']]]

def lengthy(a):
   return len(a)
```

expected output

```
ouptut = [5, [6, 7], [6, [9, 5]]]
```

My actual scenario is, of course a really extensive function than that of `lengthy()`. The actual use case list can however be not exceeding 20 elements and at the most 5 levels of nesting. So I would prefer a solution without using generator functions. However if undeniable, please do also specify the ways to convert the generator to normal form.

Answers are also open to other functions and alternatives to map, if the solution can be arrived at comfortably. I am curious to know if there exists any special library or built-ins which can solve this. Do have a say even if the answer doesn't involve the use of `map` functions.

Comment: Have you tried recursion?

Comment: I tried and failed. I am recursively experiencing failures when it comes to recursions.

Comment: Can you share your recursive approach? (code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my take:

```
x = ['apple', ['banana','blossom'], ['cherry', ['jackfruit' , 'guava', ['dragonfruit', 'fruit']]]]

def lenghty(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if isinstance(x[i], str):
            x[i] = len(x[i])
        else:
            lenghty(x[i])

print(x)
lenghty(x)
print(x)
```

output:

```
['apple', ['banana', 'blossom'], ['cherry', ['jackfruit', 'guava', ['dragonfruit', 'fruit']]]]
[5, [6, 7], [6, [9, 5, [11, 5]]]]
```